# capture values from a simple select query TADOQuery Delphi

Tags: mysql, string, delphi, textbox

I am having issues returning the value gotten from a simple SELECT query using TADOQuery

here is my code below:

```
  dbWizconQuery.SQL.Clear;
  dbWizconQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM test');
  tb_wizconValues.Items.Add('' + dbWizconQuery.SQL.GetText);

  dbWizconQuery.ExecSQL;
  processed := IntToStr(dbWizconQuery.FieldByName ('input' ).Value);
  tb_wizconValues.Items.Add('' + processed);
```

I get the first print out in my textbox ok, with the SQL String
 but then i dont get the value coming out.

Can you see why this might be?

Processed is a String and input is an INT(5) which comes out AsString

Kind Regards,

Jordan

Comment: Call `Open` instead of `ExecSQL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in delphi **ExecSQL** is used when you want to do an

```
UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE
```

when you want to do a select call **open** or just set the query to

```
active := true;
```

**you can get multiple results back by using this code:**

```
dbWizconQuery.SQL.Clear;
dbWizconQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM test';
dbWizconQuery.Open; // or dbWizconQuery.Active := True;
while not dbWizconQuery.eof do
begin
  ShowMessage(dbWizconQuery.FieldByName('FieldName').AsString); // this shows the fields value
  dbWizconQuery.Next; //use this line or you will get an infinite loop
end;
dbWizconQuery.Close; //closes the dataset
```

**for executing statements like UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE use it like this:**

```
dbWizconQuery.SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM test WHERE ID = 1';
dbWizconQuery.ExecSQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExecSQL` is used for statements that don't return a rowset, such as `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE`. For a `SELECT`, you need to use `Open` instead:

```
dbWizconQuery.SQL.Clear;
dbWizconQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM test');
tb_wizconValues.Items.Add('' + dbWizconQuery.SQL.GetText);

dbWizconQuery.Open;
processed := IntToStr(dbWizconQuery.FieldByName ('input' ).Value);
tb_wizconValues.Items.Add('' + processed);
```

For more info, see the documentation for [TDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TDataSet)